# Wordpress pull images and video shortcodes from post using regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

Hoping someone can help me out with this. I'm already pulling images from wordpress posts using a regex. Can't figure out how to pull both video and images though. Sorry I suck at regex. Here's the code I'm using:

```
 <?php
    $PostContent = $post->post_content;
    $SearchPattern = '~<img [^\>]*\ />~';

// Run preg_match_all to grab all the images and save the results in $aPics
    preg_match_all( $SearchPattern, $PostContent, $allPics );

// Check to see if we have at least 1 image
    $iNumberOfPics = count($allPics[0]);

    if ( $iNumberOfPics > 0 ) {
        // Now here you would do whatever you need to do with the images
        // For this example the images are just displayed
        for ( $i=0; $i < $iNumberOfPics ; $i++ ) {
            echo '<li>' . $allPics[0][$i] . '</li>';
        };
    };
?>
```

Any Idea how to edit the searchpattern to also pull wordpress video embeds from the post content like this:

```
[video width="640" height="360" m4v="http://localhost/~TandySean/LOH/WP38/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/museum3shot_v1_iphone.m4v"]
```

Appreciate any advice. - Sean

Answer (score 1):

The first regex is matching a html `img` element. So you want to match shortcodes which contains video info.

The following regex matches what I think you want, and captures width, height and m4v attributes in groups `\1`, `\2` and `\3`

```
~(?<=\[video)\s+width="([^"]+)"\s+height="([^"]+)"\s+m4v="([^"]+)"]~
```

**EXPLAINED**

`(?<=\[video)\s+` - Match this string literally plus one or more whitespaces following it

`width="` - Match this string literally

([^"]+)"\s+ - capture everything that's not a double quote, then match a double quote plus one or more spaces

`height="` - Match this string literally

([^"]+)"\s+ - Capture everything that's not a double quote, then match a double quote plus one or more spaces

`m4v="` - Capture this string literally

`([^"]+)"]` - Capture everything that's not a double quote, then match a double quote followed by the closing square bracket

Comment: Wow thanks. That's a lot closer than I was. Now I just have to figure out how to output this to a viable video tag and include it with the images. Appreciate the help.